# Adding a start and end marker to a GeoJSON linestring

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I have a GeoJSON route that was created using ORSM which is as follows:

```
var noelev = {"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-84.477478,37.988621],[-84.477786,37.987948],etc,[-86.448045,36.984769]]}}
```

I add the data to the script using:

```
var noel = noelev;
```

I add this data to the map and it shows the line string

```
 L.geoJSON(noel, {


       }).addTo(map);
```

And I am trying to add a marker point to the start and end of this line

I have tried using:

```
   var coords = noel.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0];
   var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]), {

   }).addTo(map);
```

I get a TypeError: noel.feature is undefined
But this does not work. I have tried everything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I just used your linestring with the etc removed, and only plotting first and last

```
var noelev={
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
            [-84.477478, 37.988621],
            [-84.477786, 37.987948],
            [-86.448045, 36.984769]
        ]
    }
}

var noel = noelev;

    var osm=new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{ 
    attribution: '© <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);

    L.geoJSON(noel, {color:"red" }).addTo(map);

//Number of points in linestring
numPts = noel.geometry.coordinates.length;

    var beg = noel.geometry.coordinates[0];
    var end = noel.geometry.coordinates[numPts-1];


    L.marker([beg[1],beg[0]]).addTo(map);
    L.marker([end[1],end[0]]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bill! Thats worked perfectly!! Taken me roughly 6 hours but its done now!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

GeoJSON is Long/Lat (X,Y) Leaflet points are Lat,Lng. Also you also may want to accommodate linestrings with more then two vertices. So get a count and use it in a for loop.

This map help.

--Copy/Paste below ---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 

    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.2.4/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-tyPum7h2h36X52O2gz+Pe8z/3l+Y9S1yEUscbVs5r5aEY5dFmP1WWRY/WLLElnFHa+k1JBQZSCDGwEAnm2IxAQ=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

<style>
html, body, #map {
width : 100%;
height : 100%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

var map = L.map('map').setView([37.599000150648514,  -85.56152343750001], 8);

var noelev={
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            -84.477478,37.988621
          ],
          [
            -84.477786,37.987948
          ],
          [
            -86.448045,36.984769
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

var noel = noelev;
console.log(noel);

    var osm=new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',{ 
    attribution: '© <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(map);

 L.geoJSON(noel, {color:"red" }).addTo(map);

console.log(noel.features[0].geometry.coordinates.length); //Number of points in linestring
numPts = noel.features[0].geometry.coordinates.length;

var i;
for (i = 0; i < numPts; i++) {

    var coords = noel.features[0].geometry.coordinates[i];

    console.log(coords);  //In lng/lat not lat/lng, need to flip

    var lat = coords[1];  
    var lon =  coords[0];
    L.marker([lat,lon]).addTo(map);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but whenever I try to do noel.features I get the typeError saying noel.features is undefined?

Comment: Your GeoJSON is defined as noelev; why are you changing it to noel?  I've modified my answer to show your noel=noelev and it works. Not sure what is causing it as I don't have all your code.

Comment: I mean when it runs through the a) console.log(noel.features[0].geometry.coordinates.length) it shows noel.features as undefined. I initialised the variable, but seems the data cannot be parsed from it

Comment: Tried it on another layer with the same structure and still getting a x.features is undefined.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/zoxuvopome/edit?js,console,output   Have you run you geoJSON through http://geojsonlint.com/   Just might be the data.  Use my GeoJSON data in your code, it should work.

Comment: ok so it seems to be the noel.features that is the issue when I change it to noel.geometries.coordinates.length it pulls the array, but it draws every single point of the line string, how do I filter it to just do the start and end?

Comment: var coords = noel.features[0].geometry.coordinates[i];    Get the length   and notice the feautres[0] is the first set of coordinates Then have one for the last set which is length - 1.

Comment: var coords = noel.geometries.coordinates[i];    The i is the coordinate set, first one is 0, last one is the length-1  My data was a feature collection, thus features, yours is not.

Comment: I got it to work when I used your geoJSON data, but still no luck using my line string

Comment: when I console.log(numPts); it says undefined also.

Comment: If I call it like this:    numPts = bc.geometry.coordinates[0];
   console.log(numPts); I get a array value, but when I do it like:    numPts = bc.geometry.coordinates[i];
   console.log(numPts); I get the undefined